# Has anyone been able to establish a WinRM remote powershell session to a Windows Docker container?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, powershell-remoting, winrm

I have two non-domain VMs. Both running the same version of PowerShell. One of the VMs is hosting a transparent-networked Docker container of WindowsServerCore. The non-Docker VM has * for the trusted machines. The Docker container has Enable-PSRemoting run and is hosting a self-signed certificate. Both Docker VM ports 5985 and 5986 are accessible to the non-Docker VM as proven with a telnet session to the Docker IP on those ports. I've added new users to the Docker VM and set them up in the Administrators group. I've reset the WinRM service.

No matter what username/password combo I use, I always get access denied when trying to establish a remote PowerShell session on either HTTP or HTTPS from the non-Docker VM.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: Were you able to get any progress on this. I tried usual tricks of relaxing SSP, and even when I tried testing within the container I got "Access is denied."

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost { $PSSender }`